# Cannot resolve symbol "postDelayed"

Tags: java, android

I have an error:  Cannot resolve symbol "postDelayed". In:

```
handler.postDelayed(updateCurrentTime, 500);
```

This is some of my code:

```
package com.example.hubert.myapplication;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ClickActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Handler handler = new Handler();

    Runnable updateCurrentTime = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            money = money + 100;
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(updateCurrentTime, 500);
(...)
}
```

I read other similar questions and none of the answers are working for me.

Comment: The method [certainly exists](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,%20long)), as it has since 2008.

Comment: Unless you cut out too much code, it looks like you're trying to execute `handler#postDelayed(Runnable, long)` outside of a method. Try putting it in one.

Comment: Declare your `Handler` object global.. not local

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put your statement in a method.

Similar to this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    handler.postDelayed(updateCurrentTime, 500);

}
```

Comment: Thank you very mutch! :)